# React Redux RTK Query with multiple Parameters throws Error on providesTags function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, rtk-query

i am currently implementing React Redux RTK into my React Application and i have a Problem with Fetching Data.

I want to create an Endpoint where the Query needs multiple Parameters to work. For example, the Endpoint is `https://localhost:8080/object/id` where Object and Id are the Parameters i need to get the Data from.

I have created an Interface like this for the Query:

```
export interface ISearch {
    objectName: string,
    id: string
}
```

And my apiSlice looks like this:

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import {ISearch} from "../utils/Interfaces";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:8080/api/v1'
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Record'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getRecord: builder.query({
            query: (params: ISearch) => `/${params.objectName}/${params.id}`,
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{
                type: 'Record',
                id: arg
            }]
        })
    })
})
```

The only Problem is that i am getting the following Error on the `providesTags` function:

```
TS2322: Type '(result: any, error: FetchBaseQueryError, arg: ISearch) => { type: "Record"; id: ISearch; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResultDescription<"ObjectDefinition" | "Record", any, ISearch, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>'.   Type '(result: any, error: FetchBaseQueryError, arg: ISearch) => { type: "Record"; id: ISearch; }[]' is not assignable to type 'GetResultDescriptionFn<"ObjectDefinition" | "Record", any, ISearch, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>'.     Type '{ type: "Record"; id: ISearch; }[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly TagDescription<"ObjectDefinition" | "Record">[]'.       Type '{ type: "Record"; id: ISearch; }' is not assignable to type 'TagDescription<"ObjectDefinition" | "Record">'.         Type '{ type: "Record"; id: ISearch; }' is not assignable to type 'FullTagDescription<"ObjectDefinition" | "Record">'.           Types of property 'id' are incompatible.             Type 'ISearch' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.               Type 'ISearch' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this, I found a small tidbit that might help someone... Try setting `type: 'Record' as const` in the tag definition... it seems with RTK query, setting `id` dynamically with a number and not using `as const` in the tag definition seems to have created a type inequality.

Answer (score 0):

A query tag consists of a type and a string id. `arg` in your `providesTags` function is what you called `params` in your `query` function. So instead of using `arg` as `id` there, you maybe want to use `arg.id` or some concatenated string like `arg.object + '/' + arg.id`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your arg to the parameter you're passing, in your case the third parameter in your providesTags will be a value you're passing in your ISearch.

Answer (score 0):

This might not directly apply to this specific question, however I landed here from Google after having a similar error.

If you are making use of the [`injectEndpoints` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/code-splitting#injectendpoints) to extend an API (for [code splitting/maintenance](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) reasons most likely), then you must first "enhance" if with the [`enhanceEndpoints` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/code-splitting#enhanceendpoints).

For instance:

```
const enhancedApi = api.enhanceEndpoints({
  addTagTypes: ["Record"],
});

const yourApi = enhancedApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getRecord: builder.query({
      query: (arg: string) => `/record/${arg}`,
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => ({
        type: "Record", id: arg
      })
    })
  })
});
```

I needed to deploy this method myself in order for the tags I was returning to be considered valid.

In hindsight this felt obvious because how exactly is RTK supposed to know what the available tags are? But I wanted to provide an answer for folks who might run into a similar error but for a different reason than the OP did.